# Calculating dates in a foreach loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, foreach

I have a list of events being generated by a foreach loop in wordpress and in each list item I have a date, a value and a new date which is a calculation of both of these.

Using Jquery I can work out this calculation if there were not multiple instances of this calculation but I'm looking to adapt what I have for it work for each li. Below is the HTML I have at the moment;

```
<ul class="event-list">


<li class="event">
<div class="date">13 jun 2017</div>
<div class="value">2</div>
<div class="new-date"> in here </div> 
</li>


<li class="event">
<div class="date">15 jun 2017</div>
<div class="value">3</div>
<div class="new-date"> in here </div> 
</li>

</ul>
```

What I am looking to achieve using jquery and bearing in mind all the values in these div are generated dynamically would be the following:

```
<li class="event">
<div class="date">13 jun 2017</div>
<div class="value">2</div>
<div class="new-date"> 15 jun 2017 </div> 
</li>


<li class="event">
<div class="date">15 jun 2017</div>
<div class="value">3</div>
<div class="new-date"> 18 jun 2017 </div> 
</li>

</ul>
```

Here is a fiddle to show the work in progress https://jsfiddle.net/uo2gugda/

You can see the calculation is working for the first event but not the second, the other issue I am facing is the output of the new date - How can I format this to be 15 jun 2017 instead of Thu Jun 15 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a for each per dom element, formatting you can use moment.js, in this loop compute next day as following:

```js
function addDays(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
}

$('li.event').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var date = $this.children('.date').html();
  var days = Number($this.children('.value').html());
  var stringDate = moment(addDays(date, days)).format('DD MMM YYYY');
  $this.children('.new-date').html(stringDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="event-list">
  <li class="event">
    <div class="date">13 jun 2017</div>
    <div class="value">2</div>
    <div class="new-date"> in here </div> 
  </li>
  <br>
  <li class="event">
    <div class="date">15 jun 2017</div>
    <div class="value">3</div>
    <div class="new-date"> in here </div> 
  </li> 
 </ul>
```